# Save value of hidden field and radio input value when a radio button is checked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to collect the value of the radio button into the database, but I also need another value collected based on the radio button selected. The values will rarely change so having a front-end solution seems the way to go.  The code below works as it should, but I feel the jQuery functions can be combined and dried out considerably. Is there a way I can combine the four functions into a single function?

**My form data**

```
...
<%= f.radio_button :plaque_size, '16" x 8"' %> 16" x 8" / $1,800 Donation
<%= f.radio_button :plaque_size, '12" x 8"' %> 12" x 8" / $1,500 Donation
<%= f.radio_button :plaque_size, '8" x 8"' %> 8" x 8" / $1,200 Donation

<%= f.text_field :plaque_cost, class: 'hidden' %>
...
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
  $('#plaqueorder_plaque_size_16_x_8').change(plaque_size_16_x_8);
  $('#plaqueorder_plaque_size_12_x_8').change(plaque_size_12_x_8);
  $('#plaqueorder_plaque_size_8_x_8').change(plaque_size_8_x_8)
});

function plaque_size_16_x_8() {
  $('#plaque_cost').val('180000');
}
function plaque_size_12_x_8() {
  $('#plaque_cost').val('120000');
}
function plaque_size_8_x_8() {
  $('#plaque_cost').val('95000');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modifiy your html first with two goals...

1. Set a field for each radio button that will allow you to obtain the corresponding donation amount in your jQuery code. You can set a `value` attribute, or a `data-donation` attribute, etc.
2. Set a way to select all the radio buttons easily in jQuery. A class, for example.

I don't now rails, but I guess it has to be easy to do. The idea is that the html result looks similar to this...

```
<input type="radio" class="rbdonation" value="180000"...
<input type="radio" class="rbdonation" value="120000"...
<input type="radio" class="rbdonation" value="95000"...
```

Then, you can do what you want in one jQuery event function...

```
$('input.rbdonation').change(function() {
    $('#plaque_cost').val(this.value);
});
```

Or if you need the `value` field for other purpose, you can use the `data-*` attribute...

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="rbdonation" data-donation="180000"...
<input type="radio" class="rbdonation" data-donation="120000"...
<input type="radio" class="rbdonation" data-donation="95000"...
```

JQUERY:

```
$('input.rbdonation').change(function() {
    $('#plaque_cost').val($(this).data('donation'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I would have set the `plaque_cost` value directly into the radio button, but there is already a value set for the radio button which is the plaque size as a string value.  I need the plaque size and the plaque cost both persist to the database.

Comment: In understand. So then you can go with the `data-donation` attibute option. Check the example in my answer. Those `data-*` fields attributes where designed for that purpose, to keep additional information associated to an html element.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just make one plaque_size function and pass in the value you want rather than converting? You'll habe just one function if you do:

```
function plaque_size (size) {
  $('#plaque_cost').val (size);
}
```

and call it like so:

$('#plaqueorder_plaque_size_16_x_8').change(plaque_size ('180000'));

Comment: not working.  I added `console.log(size)` to the `plaque_size` function and `size` is not being passed down.

Comment: I'm afraid `.change()` function doesn't allow to pass function parameters like that. If you want to do this, your handler function should expect an object `function plaque_size(info) { $('#plaque_cost').val(info.data.size); }` and you'll have to call it with `$('#plaqueorder_plaque_size_16_x_8').change({ size: '180000' },plaque_size);`